# How to solve to my code on vb.net in changing value?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub QuantityTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles QuantityTextBox.TextChanged

    Dim i      As Integer
    Dim total  As Integer
    Dim PPrice As Integer

    i      = QuantityTextBox.Text
    PPrice = ProductPriceTextBox.Text
    total  = Integer.Parse(i) * Integer.Parse(PPrice)

    TotalPriceTextBox.Text = total

End Sub
```

this is my problem when i start the vb.net:

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

I want is when i input a number in quantity textbox automatic compute to totalpricetextbox

Comment: Error happens on which line? Please add to your question.

Answer (score 2):

- The local variable `i` is declared as an `Integer`.
- `QuantityTextBox.Text` is a `String`.
- You cannot convert from `String` to `Integer` because while the string "123" could be converted to an integer easily enough, the string "abc" can not.
- You must therefore explicitly tell the computer to convert the value by calling `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse`

Do this:

```
i        = Integer.Parse( QuantityTextBox.Text )
pPrice   = Integer.Parse( ProductPriceTextBox.Text )
total    = i * pPrice

TotalPriceTextBox.Text = total.ToString("C")
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.
and now this is my error

Comment: @KrissyNoriega I suggest you read the MSDN documentation for how the `Parse` method words.